# Get a reference of a derived class object through a base class pointer

Tags: c++, class

I have a vector of base class pointers to store different derived classes. I need to access methods/objects that may be present on a derived class, but not on the base class.

I've tried using a function in the form of something like `base* getObject(int idx);` and then using `dynamic_cast`, and `static_cast` from `Base*` into `Derived&`, but that doesn't seem to work, as compilation failed.

My base class looks something like this:

```cpp
        class Base {
          int a, b;
        public:
          virtual void f1(int) = 0;
          virtual void f2(int, int) = 0;
        };
```

And my derived classes look something like this:

```
        class Derived : public Base {
          std::vector <int> myVector;
        public:
          void f1(int ai) override {}
          void f2(int ai, int bi) override {}
          int getFromVector(int idx) { return myVector[idx]; }
        }
```

The vector that should contain the derived classes looks like this:

```
        std::vector <Base*> derivedObjects;
```

What I would like to do, is to get something from the `derivedObjects` vector, and access, say, `getFromVector()`.

Comment: *"I need to access methods/objects that may be present on a derived class, but not on the base class."* This suggests the base class' interface is too poor. Clients should be able to do all their work in terms of the base class - that's kind of the point of polymorphism.

Comment: That said, you are looking for `*static_cast<Derived*>(base_ptr);`, or alternatively `static_cast<Derived&>(*base_ptr)`. A variation using `dynamic_cast` is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thing is, the base class models a device. All devices (as modeled by my implementation) should be able to "read" and "write"  a value. Though, its up to the derived class how, and from where these reads and writes go to/come from. thats why the derived class doesnt have an std::vector, and the derived class does

Comment: @Aureal Then the base class should have pure virtual `read` and `write` functions, which are properly implemented in each derived class, potentially using the `myVector` in one such derived class having it as member. The user of these classes (e.g. the holder of `derivedObjects`) then just calls `read` and `write` on the `Base*` pointers and doesn't care about the additional member that the derived class uses.

Comment: _"doesn't seem to work"_ tells us nothing about your problem. Why does it not seem to work? What did you observe, and what did you expect? See also [mcve] -- you might have just made a typo in the code we have not seen, but there is no way to know that.

Comment: Your code shows that you already know how to use virtual methods. That happens to be exactly how you go about getting "something from the derivedObjects vector, and access, say, getFromVector()". This is exactly what virtual methods are for. This is precisely their purpose and goal in life. That is exactly how you go about doing that. If it "doesn't work", you have to explain exactly how it "doesn't work", otherwise it's not clear what you expect everyone else to tell you.

Comment: Actually, Igor's answer was correct. As for background, I designed an emulator with a bus structure, where different devices may connect to the bus, with the basic functionality of being able to send a value to that device, read a value, and translate an address. That's defined in the "device" class, then. Derived classes may be things like memory, keyboard, mouse, etc. Which do implement all of Base's virtual functions, but may contain other methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Igor Tandetnik that the interface class may need to be designed better.
With the given statement, dynamic_cast can be used, but you must remember that a dynamic cast is a try, which may fail. Since you are using a reference of derived class in the case of cast operation failure, you will have to catch the exception and proceed accordingly.

For example, if you have Derived1 and Derived2 classes, and you are trying to dynamically cast a Derived1 object to a Derived2 reference, then a bad_cast exception will be thrown. This happens because a reference object cannot be set to null.
As an alternative, you can try to cast it to a pointer of derived type and not a reference.
After trying to dynamically cast, you can check if the pointer is null.

Further reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/